# What are the advantages of using ThemeProvider vs importing the theme directly in Styled Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I was wondering if using Styled Components with `ThemeProvider` passing down the theme wouldn't bring performance issues, since you would need to use hundreds or even thousands of arrow functions to access theme that way.

My real question is: which approach is better and why?

**Option 1**

```js
const InputHelpText = styled.p`
    font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.text.s};
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondaryLight};
    margin-top: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing.xs};
`;
```

**Option 2**

```js
import { theme } from './theme';

const InputHelpText = styled.p`
    font-size: ${theme.text.s};
    color: ${theme.colors.secondaryLight};
    margin-top: ${theme.spacing.xs};
`;
```

Comment: I would say that if your theme gets updated dynamically, let's say for example you have a dark or light theme, you will watch those changes in your theme provider and using the option 1 will be the only one that will work, if your theme is static and won't change I think both options are good.

Comment: Yap, that's correct, I guess my question in more in terms of performance and figuring out if using context brings performance issues vs importing theme directly on every file

Comment: I think is the same because if your theme is static and you use it inside the ThemeProvider you are never going to re render the consumer components because you're not changing the theme value. React context only causes re renders if you change the value, so I think is safe to go with the ThemeProvider, but I mean if is static I don't see any issue in just importing the theme in the styled component file since that's easier than calling this ${(props) => props.theme.text.s}.